# The getNextEntry method of ZipInputStream throws a ZipException: Invalid zip entry path: /xxxx error when running on an Android 14 device

Tags: android, zipinputstream

Firstly, the necessary condition for the issue to occur is that the project is set with a targetSdkVersion of 34. The same code, with a targetSdkVersion of 33, does not encounter the issue on the same Android 14 device.

My code is as follows:

```
    fun unzip(
        sourceFile: File, targetDirPath: String,
        onSuccess: (() -> Unit)?, onError: ((msg: String?) -> Unit)?
    ) {
        try {
            var sumLength: Long = 0
            val zis = ZipInputStream(
                BufferedInputStream(
                    FileInputStream(sourceFile)
                )
            )
            zis.use {
                var ze: ZipEntry?
                var count: Int
                val buffer = ByteArray(8192)
                while (zis.nextEntry.also { ze = it } != null) {
                    val file = File(targetDirPath, ze!!.name)
                    val dir: File = if (ze!!.isDirectory) file else file.parentFile
                    if (!dir.isDirectory && !dir.mkdirs()) {
                        throw FileNotFoundException(
                            "Failed to ensure directory: " +
                                    dir.absolutePath
                        )
                    }


                    if (ze!!.isDirectory) {
                        continue
                    }
                    val fout = FileOutputStream(file)
                    fout.use {
                        while (zis.read(buffer).also { count = it } != -1) {
                            sumLength += count.toLong()
                            fout.write(buffer, 0, count)
                            fout.flush()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            onSuccess?.invoke()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            onError?.invoke(e.message)
        }
    }
```

I've looked into the official documentation and haven't found any specific handling required for unzip operations when upgrading from targetSdkVersion 33 to targetSdkVersion 34.

Detailed stack error is as follows:

```
14:56:54.757  7949-7949  System.err           com....aes  W  java.util.zip.ZipException: Invalid zip entry path: /xxx
14:56:54.761  7949-7949  System.err           com....aes  W     at com.android.internal.os.SafeZipPathValidatorCallback.onZipEntryAccess(SafeZipPathValidatorCallback.java:52)
14:56:54.761  7949-7949  System.err           com....aes  W     at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.readLOC(ZipInputStream.java:335)
14:56:54.761  7949-7949  System.err           com....aes  W     at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.getNextEntry(ZipInputStream.java:135)
```

Does anyone know what caused this? Thank you very much.

Comment: You are unzipping. When was that file zipped? On 14 too? Target version?

Comment: `byte[] inputBytes` Pretty unclear where those bytes come from.

Comment: This is not reproducible for us. You should give complete code where you first zip a file.

Comment: I've updated the code and also identified the issue.

Comment: we are also facing issues like this, can you help us https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77756885/android-14-issue-java-util-zip-zipexception-invalid-zip-entry-path-res-l3mk

Comment: help on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77756885/android-14-issue-java-util-zip-zipexception-invalid-zip-entry-path-res-l3mk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue and also identified the solution.
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/behavior-changes-14

For apps targeting Android 14, Android prevents the Zip Path Traversal Vulnerability in the following way: ZipFile(String) and ZipInputStream.getNextEntry() throws a ZipException if zip file entry names contain ".." or start with "/".

Apps can opt-out from this validation by calling dalvik.system.ZipPathValidator.clearCallback().

So, there are two possible solutions: either reprocess your zip package or implement the code to disable the validation:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 34) {
    ZipPathValidator.clearCallback()
}
```

Additionally, you can also listen to the relevant callbacks.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 34) {
    ZipPathValidator.setCallback(object : ZipPathValidator.Callback {
        override fun onZipEntryAccess(path: String) {
           // print log...
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Interesting. But i never had this problem on my 14 device.

Comment: @blackapps It must be an app with targetSdkVersion 34 to encounter the issue. If compilesdk is 34 but target is 33, there won't be any problem on Android 14. Certainly, provided that the zip package is not well-structured.